# Should not abuse firebaseRef.on('value')?

Tags: firebase

[In the firebase API doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), it says `firebaseRef.on('value')` would get the whole data from firebase at that location whenever there is any data added/changed/removed in the firebase. If I want to keep my website real-time update. For minimizing the data transfer from firebase (and saving money in firebase pricing plan), should I replace the `firebaseRef.on('value')` with `firebaseRef.on('child_added')`, `firebaseRef.on('child_removed')` and `firebaseRef.on('child_changed')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in bandwidth usage between `on('value'` and `on('child_added'` (and its siblings). In both cases the Firebase client will need to load and synchonize all the data at the location (or in the query).